# Knockout function and Google Map

Tags: javascript, google-maps, knockout.js

I am trying to create a map with different locations and I am using knockout binding to display some features on my html view. 
I have a function that enables me to create various locations.

I want each location to have its own marker. When rendering the map, I display some defaults locations. But I have this error: Uncaught ReferenceError: google is not defined

Here is my code.

```
    defaultMarkers =[
    new Locations("Ike's Food & Cocktails","(612) 746-4537","50 S 6th St","",44.97818705436708,-93.27229499816895),
    new Locations("Eli's East Food & Cocktails","(612) 331-0031","815 E Hennepin Ave","#",44.99128282822349,-93.24738264083862),
    new Locations("Midnord Empanada Food truck","unavailable","unavailable","#",44.97596890779807,-93.27159452192403),
    new Locations("Maruso Street Food Bar","(612) 333-0100", "715 E Hennepin Ave","#",44.97760063074655,-93.2754345812601),
    new Locations("The House Of Hunger Food Truck","unavailable","unavailable","#",44.97611524414878,-93.27146677068872)];


   var map;
   function initMap() {

     var mapOptions = {
       center: {lat: 38.9165087, lng: -77.2482606}, 
       zoom: 13
      }
     map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), mapOptions); 

    // add defaults markers on map
    updateMap(map, defaultMarkers);

   }
    function Locations(name, contact, fulladress, url, lat, lng){
      var self = this;
      self.name= name;
      self.contact = contact;
      self.url = url;
      self.fulladress = fulladress;
      self.lat = lat;
      self.lng = lng;
      self.showMe = ko.observable(true);    
      self.marker = new google.maps.Marker({     // HERE IS THE LINE WHERE THE ERROR OCCUR
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(lat, lng),
        map: map,
    });}
    function MapViewModel() {

    var self = this;
    self.listVenues = ko.observableArray(defaultMarkers);
    }
```

Can you help me figure out where I am doing wrong?

.

Comment: Is your javascript files correctly included in the HTML ?

Comment: Yes they are.
1. I included knockout.js
2. I included google map call
3. I included my js file

Comment: Did you correctly included the google maps script : `<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap" async defer></script>` like this?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your script is:
 `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=places&key=APIKEY"></script>`

Not including the `type="text/javascript"` may be messing you up.